# CSS or JS transition for button that changes size from text changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have an Angular app with a button that has a label of "+"

On mouse-over I call `element.append(' Add a New Number');` This adds that text new to the + in the label.

Use clicks the button, new number is added, label of button is returned to "+"

I would like to animate the button size change and/or the txt label change.  So far, just adding a css transition to `width` does nothing.

Thoughts?

UPDATE:
To help clarify, this is a bootstrap input group button.  I don't want to set widths or css transforms, to avoid breaking the group either here or at other screen sizes.

here are the 2 states:

[image]

[image]

I was simply letting the existing button stretch due to the injection of more words.

Comment: Could you show your CSS?

Comment: What is the actual code you are using? `transition width` isn't enough to ensure you are working with the correct syntax.

Comment: I don't think this is an Angular specific puzzle. I think it's more about having an inherent width - and then putting something somewhere and then  having a new width. I don't think that it's enough information for native transitions to work with. It's like "animate from auto to ?" Here's a little test http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/tcps4hug/ --- I think you'll have to somehow put the width of those numbers in there and then animate to that width and fade in the number with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that with bootstrap CSS and Angular - it will be more complex, but this is how I would go about it programatically. You'll have to deal with the model and the data differently - and you should probably build a directive to repeat the action and integrate with Angular smoothly:

### HTML

```
<div class="thing">+ <span id="message">
    <span id='target'></span>
</span></div>
```

### JavaScript

```
$('.thing').hover( function() {
  var originalWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
  $messageHolder = $(this).find('#message');
  $target = $(this).find('#target');
  $target.text('Some helpful text');
  var targetWidth = $target.outerWidth();
  $messageHolder.animate({
    width: targetWidth
  }, {
    duration: 200,
    complete: function() {
      $messageHolder.animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 500);
    }
  });
});

$('.thing').on('click', function() {
  $target = $(this).find('#target');
  $target.empty();
  $messageHolder = $(this).find('#message');
  $messageHolder.animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    duration: 200,
    complete: function() {
      $messageHolder.animate({
        width: 0
      }, 200);
    }
  });

});
```

I'm sure that Angular's ng-animate library watches the dom and also has an excellent way of animating things as they change in the model/controller or whatever they are calling it. This is probably something what it looks like behind the scenes.

Good luck!

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/tcps4hug/3/)

Answer (score 1):

I am probably guessing you don't have a predefined width. anyways you could use `transform-origin` and `scale` to achieve such an effect

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/a2e1qke6/1/)**

HTML:

```
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

CSS:

```
#btn {
    outline: none;
    border:none;
    background: orange;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    -o-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
}
#btn:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(1.2);
    -o-transform: scaleX(1.2);
    transform: scaleX(1.2);
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin:0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
    -o-transform-origin:0 0;
    transform-origin:0 0;
}
```

you should use CSS transforms for animations rather than a property like `width`. The animation is slightly jerky , so you might want to work on it a bit more.

Comment: I wouldn't feel that great about absolute values for things with type and dynamic values.

Comment: The line `transition: width 3s;` I think you intended to be `transition: width .3s;`, cause it now moves way too drowsy.

Comment: @AhmadBaktashHayeri demonstration purpose ;) ... sheriffderek , hmmmm , yeah i am thinking of an alternative way to suggest in the mean time !

Comment: This doesn't take into account the dynamically added string of numbers that is visually inserted / unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: I can't set CSS transforms, as the button is part of a bootstrap input group, and needs to be responsive

Answer (score 1):

You had jQuery tagged, so this is how I would do it.

All the transitions. fade + animate

```
function changeButtonText(button, text){
    // jQuery it
    $button = $(button);
    
    // get orinal css'es
    oooon = $button.css('text-align');
    doooo = $button.css('overflow');
    treee = $button.css('white-space');
    $button.css('text-align', 'left').css('overflow', 'hidden').css('white-space', 'nowrap');;
    
    // get new width first
    $tmpBtn = $button.clone().append(text).css('opacity', '0.0').appendTo('body');
    newWidth = $tmpBtn.outerWidth();
    $tmpBtn.remove();
    
    // now stretch the button out
    $button.animate({width: newWidth+"px"});
    
    // fade texts into the butt
    $button.append('<span style="display:none">'+text+'</span>');
    $btnText = $button.find('span').fadeIn('slow');
    
    return {
        'text-align':oooon,
        'overflow':doooo,
        'white-space':treee
    };
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfak5184/1/)